# How to integrate Devise and SAML?

Tags: devise

What is the best way to get SAML working with the widely used https://github.com/plataformatec/devise?

https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable doesn't do signed/encrypted auth requests and that's a deal breaker for us, and the usual sources haven't helped.

Devise's Omniauth integration, for example, requires an app ID and secret that Onelogin's SAML connector doesn't provide.

Comment: Is it still true that https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable doesn't support encrypted auth requests? The README seems to suggest they do: https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable#signing-and-encrypting-authentication-requests-and-assertions

Comment: It's been a long time, but as far as I remember they do support them, it's just the setup wasn't well documented. I figured it out then below, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996936.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Devise config's parameters were wrong. I documented the correct settings in a fork/PR:

https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml#devise-integration

Comment: This solution does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

So, the answer that worked for me is to use the gemlfile and omniauth.rb settings as outlined in https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml#usage and then to follow devise's omniauth tutorial at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview, replacing facebook with SAML. Note that you mightn't need the UID field mentioned in the tutorial, depending on how your IdP stores their users (and you wouldn't get a permanent UID if you use the transient nameid format). Use whatever uniquely identifies your user at the IdP, which is quite possibly an email address.

The devise.rb stuff added by ioblomov doesn't seem to add anything and in fact causes an issue if you do it as well as doing an omniauth.rb file. This creates a situation where the IdP does two callbacks, one using the omniauth.rb settings and another using the devise.rb settings. Given that the devise.rb settings are not complete (they don't have a consumer url for example), I can't see how even having it on its own could ever work. It is not clear to me what "devise integration" even means in the context of omniauth-saml. Once you get an auth response back (which you will just from using the omniauth.rb settings), then all you have to do is use the devise method sign_in_and_redirect in your callback controller and then you have all the usual devise stuff available to you for that user. I will submit a PR to omniauth-saml but I wouldn't be holding my breath as the project appears to be sporadically maintained at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with recently to hook a rails app up to a university network using Shibboleth for SSO. I ended up using devise, omniauth and running on Apache with mod-shib2. I am not sure if you are using Shibboleth specifically but it is built on top of SAML. The lightweight rack-saml implementation did not work for me.